# Input of empty space at the end of a line doesn't get you on to the next one for chats

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat

When using Chrome, input spaces at the end of a line does not make the cursor go to a new line. Deletion of those extra spaces at the end of the line only works after deleting all the extra spaces not visible at the end.

[image: space]

I have checked for the same problem on Firefox, this does not happen.

The same problem occurs on mobile using Safari however.

Comment: Wow.  That's awful.  Shame.

Answer (score 4):

This is simply how `textarea` works on Chrome. It is not something we control or can change.

Try a `textarea` on any site with Chrome - you will see the same thing.

Declining, as this isn't something we can (or should) fix.

Comment: Maybe rich text editor instead of ordinary textarea... ;-)

Comment: Naw. Lets stay with standard web controls.